# Can I say "Es geht um eine Frage"?

Tags: meaning, difference

Can I use the phrase

> Es geht um eine Frage.

instead of

> Ich habe eine Frage.

What are the differences between them and can I use both for the same situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Es geht um eine Frage," means, "it goes to the question of... " (an abstract concept, e.g, politeness, righteousness, scientific method, etc., in a general,  objective sense of the word).

"Ich habe eine Frage, means "I have a question about..." (that is particular to me).

Apart from sharing the word "question," the two expressions are not alike.

Answer (score 4):

> Es geht um eine Frage …

typically introduces sentences like this:

> Es geht um eine Frage der Gerechtigkeit.
>
> Es geht um eine Frage, die nicht leicht zu beantworten ist.

So, no, this phrase does **not** replace *Ich habe eine Frage.*

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Janka's answer (which is correct and sufficient) I would - just for exploration of the depths and widths of language usage - present one possible context where "Es geht um eine Frage" anyway would work in the sense of "Ich habe eine Frage", i.e. for preparing an interlocutor to listening to a question:

> Entschuldigen Sie bitte, dürfte ich mich kurz an Sie wenden? Es geht um eine Frage: Ich möchte gerne wissen, ob...

Of course, out there in the wild you would not often meet a polite and circumstantial address like this. In much more frequent use is the famously rude

> Ich hab da mal ne Frage...